# Volume set to 22% by itself all the time - how to find the cause?

Tags: volume-control

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have a problem with the audio volume. It adjusts itself to 22% all the time. I can control it, but it goes back to 22% within seconds.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

[This ubuntu.com community Sound Troubleshooting Procedure provides lots of informations and places to look into.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Some background software or default setting will likely be causing this. As this is not exactly a solution but a pointer to some procedures I would prefer not to post it as an answer...

Try to provide some more details, I'd say.

[Logs w/ and w/o GUI to look into...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) There is an audio section.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that guide and post a solution here if I find it. Question: If there is a background software causing this, can I see this in a specific log file?